# Why the div element is not appearing Infront of the current div but its only visible at the static div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The problem is when I click the Option (button) that appears on every div after I fetch the data using the While loop it only appears the top div but not the current div that I am viewing. This is the picture when I click the Option it only appears the one place:
[image: This is the picture when i click the Option it only appears the one place.]

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','users_data_allocation');

$feeder = "SELECT * FROM `trade_feed_post`";
$runfeed = mysqli_query($connect,$feeder);



while ($showfeed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runfeed)) {
    # code...
    $feedAcc = $showfeed['OwnerACC'];
$feedDate = $showfeed['Date and time'];
$feedQuote = $showfeed['quote'];
$feedBuys = $showfeed['No.of buys'];

echo "
<div class=\"border\">
                    <p>".$feedAcc."</p>
                    <button onclick=\"showOpt()\">Option</button>
                    <div class=\"menu\">
                        This is menu.
                    </div>
                </div>

";

}


            ?>

            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>ShowData</title>
                <style>
                    .border{
                        background-color: black;
                        color: white;
                        border: 2px solid red;
                        height: 220px;
                        width: 400px;
                        font-family: ebrima;
                        font-size: 25px;
                        padding-left: 10px;
                    }
                    .menu{
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>
                <script>
                    function showOpt() {
                        document.querySelector('.menu').style.display = 'block';
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector()` only selects the first element that matches. If you want a specific one, you should identify it with an id or use `querySelectorAll(...)[index]`;

Comment: querySelectorAll() does not work at this case i don't know why.

Comment: Please show your attempt(s) that included `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `this` element parameter to `<button onclick=\"showOpt(this)\">Option</button>`.

Then change function so that will find correct `.menu` for `button` (using common parent `.border`)

```
function showOpt(elem) {
    elem.closest(".border").querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'block';
}
```